# How do I get the values in a class by using a classmethod in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a class with a bunch of values attached to it. I would like to get a specific value using a classmethod, or return a list of values. However I just don't seem to be able to get it right.

```
class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str.__str__(self)

class BunchOfCreatures(StrEnum):
    SPIDERS: str = "Spiders"
    BEETLES: str = "Beetles"
    HORSES: str = "Horses"

    @classmethod
    def get_that_string(cls, BunchOfCreatures: BunchOfCreatures) -> List[str]:
        return [item.value for item in BunchOfCreatures]
```

What I want to be able to do it say BunchOfCreatures.get_that_string(HORSES), or even a list that includes multiple things, such as HORSES, BEETLES, and have a list containing all the associated string values.

The reason I don't go straight for BunchOfCreatures.HORSES is that I sometimes need to give a list of values to return or compare.

Comment: what is `HORSES` in `BunchOfCreatures.get_that_string(HORSES)` or did you mean `BunchOfCreatures.get_that_string(BunchOfCreatures.HORSES)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to return any sublist of the creatures. It also has a branch to return ALL if no creatures are specified:

```
from enum import Enum                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                      
class StrEnum(str, Enum):                                                                                                             
    def __str__(self) -> str:                                                                                                         
        return str.__str__(self)                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
class BunchOfCreatures(StrEnum):                                                                                                      
    SPIDERS: str = "Spiders"                                                                                                          
    BEETLES: str = "Beetles"                                                                                                          
    HORSES: str = "Horses"                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                      
    @classmethod                                                                                                                      
    def list_creatures(cls, creatures=None):                                                                                          
        if creatures==None:                                                                                                           
            return list(map(lambda c: c.value, cls))                                                                                  
        return [c.value for c in creatures]                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
print(BunchOfCreatures.list_creatures())                                                                                              
print(BunchOfCreatures.list_creatures([BunchOfCreatures.HORSES]))
```

Note that you do need to append the name of the class (`BunchOfCreatures.HORSES`) in order to pass something meaningful as an argument. Passing simply `HORSES` will result in BackTrace (`HORSES` hasn't been defined outside of the class method!)